# Camera2 in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, android-viewpager

I am trying to set up a viewPager with two fragments. I am using the v4 support library for the FragmentPagerAdapter as in the sample Android Activity in Android Studio, this is how it looks:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return CameraFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

}
```

My issue comes because I try to implement the Google [Camera2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) example as my camera fragment. These Fragments are native Fragments, while the PagerAdapter expects support.v4.Fragments.

I have tried to use the v13 FragmentPagerAdapter, but this cannot use the v4.FragmentManager, and it doesn't have its own FragmentManager.

I also tried converting the CameraFragment to a v4 Fragment, but there is some code in there that doesn't compile to the v4 support library.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this problem?

Comment: I decided to implement it in another way, but I might decide to go back to this implementation later, since I think I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the solution to this issue as I was having the same problem. Keep in mind I am not a highly experienced Android developer, so my solution could present flaws, however, I think this may be of help to you. *Your Mileage May Vary*.

I am using the `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` with the native `Android.app.Fragment` and `Android.app.FragmentManger`. The `V4 Support Library` is used for the rest of the relevant imports to this functionality.

**import(s)**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

My other Fragments follow the same design as depicted in your post.

**Notes**

1. I've added the `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'` build dependency to the `build.gradle` file. According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v13), this is the latest build dependency version for this library. You can see how to add build dependencies, [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html).
2. I believe it is recommended to extend your `Activity` that you will be using for the `ViewPager` from `Fragment` if you're using native `android.app.Fragment`, but my code seems to work while extending from [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) as well.